# "The world sucks according to the famous principle"

Tags: meaning

*The world sucks according to the famous principle. Never give a sucker an even break.*

Could you explain to me the point of this aphorism? My probably false reading is as follows: Because the world is bad or injust, treat in bad manner those who are naive, stupid… Is this "cynical" reading OK?

Comment: Are you asking the meaning of *The world sucks*, or *Never give a sucker an even break?* They're very different "sayings, principles", and there's no obvious reason why your two sentences should appear consecutively. Btw - I'm no great fan of "overpunctuation", but you can't really avoid the need for a comma after ***sucks***.

Comment: Source? If I saw "The earth sucks according to the famous principle" by itself, I would assume that it was referring to a graffito common in my high school years (late 1970s/early 1980s) "Gravity is a myth. The earth sucks." (meaning, life is always unpleasant). The addition of the attrib Fields quote immediately afterward confuses the issue: is *that* 'the famous principle' referred to? If so, it changes the focus from 'the earth' (in general) to 'a sucker' (one person in general or in particular).

Comment: In either case, 'suck(s)/sucker' has a different meaning in each sentence. In the first sentence 'sucks' means 'is unpleasant', in the second, 'a sucker' is a fool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posited fame of the principle "The world sucks" is questionable; the debate over the truth of that statement predates Pangloss and Martin, and will likely never be resolved.

It is a far simpler matter to consider separately the aphorism "Never give a sucker an even break," which is commonly associated with the American vaudevillian and actor W. C. Fields. In *You Can't Cheat an Honest Man (1939),* Fields's character Larson E. Whipsnade expresses its complete form:

> As my dear old grandfather Litvak said (just before they swung the trap,) he said "You can't cheat an honest man. Never give a sucker an even break or smarten up a chump."

However, *Bartlett's Familiar Quotations* attributes the saying to a remark made by Edward Francis Albee, who died in 1930. In any case, your cynical interpretation is accurate. The aphorism means "If a person is a fool, it is justifiable to take advantage of that person."